# ffmpeg selects shortest movie but leaves full length audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I've created a tool to create a grid of movies, like in the Brady Bunch opening. It's a cool, funny effect.

[Here's a sample movie showing the grid.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6bhi60xOig&feature=youtu.be)

[image: Grid of movies in ffmpeg output]

The problem is that ffmpeg is choosing the *shortest* movie to determine the maximum length of overlaid videos, but still using the *full* length of the first audio track to determine the overall output movie length.

So all my videos stop moving when the shortest one ends, but the audio plays on for full length of the first movie.

How can I either (1) set the length of the output movie to the *longest input movie* or (2) match the audio length to the shortest movie length as well?

[Gist of my script](https://gist.github.com/wanderingstan/5ec0a6802d87f3934796).

Based on [this ffmpeg example usage](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) which exhibits the same audio problem:

```
ffmpeg
    -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -i 3.avi -i 4.avi
    -filter_complex "
        nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
        [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
        [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
        [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
        [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
        [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
        [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240
    "
    -c:v libx264 output.mkv
```

Comment: As for "(1)" what do you want to happen to the shorter videos when they end (but the longer continues)? Show last frame, just vanish?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The default behavior of looping the last frame is fine. Or turning black. ...I've just discovered `[0:a] atrim=duration=6.6` will force the output to stop after 6.6 seconds. I'm now working on how to determine the best length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I set the length of the output movie to the longest input movie?

Remove the `shortest=1` from each overlay. By default the shortest input for the overlay will simply stop and the last frame will be repeated while the longer input continues. This behavior can be changed with the `eof_action` overlay option. See [overlay filter docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).

> How can I match the audio length to the shortest movie length as well?

Add the `-shortest` output option. This is a different option that the overlay `shortest` option; place it outside the [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description) as an output option (before the output file). Now the final output file will be the same duration as the shortest stream: either the video from the filtergraph, or the audio from one of your inputs (which one exactly depends on the [default stream selection behavior](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) because I don't see you doing anything with the audio in the command).

<sub>IIRC, there may be an existing bug involving filtering and `-shortest` not doing what is expected, but I can't recall the details at the moment and am too lazy to look. Just something to be aware of.</sub>

Comment: I'll post future questions in SuperUser. I just posted one that may be quick for you: http://superuser.com/questions/991714/select-audio-from-second-input-file-for-ffmpeg-movie-overlay

Comment: Is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1684633/ffmpeg-shortest-not-working-when-using-filter-complex-with-audio-and-video-fil) the bug you were talking about? It appears to have been an issue since at least 2014

Comment: @pigeonburger Seems so, but I'm not remembering any details.