# How to change video speed only while adding a same-speed separated audio stream with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, frame-rate

I'm using ffmpeg for video filter.

But, When I changed video speed, that time I got issue

- **Audio is longer than video** :

  ```
  ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4  -filter:v setpts=0.5*PTS -shortest -y -preset ultrafast OUTPUT.mp4
  ```

I want to set audio's length same as video's length.

- **shortest** =   to extend audio streams to the same length as the video stream

In my case, `shortest` is not working. Video file and audio file, both are different and then after merging in a video file. Video's last frame stop and audio is continued working.

Comment: I have a same problem. you should see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330279/ffmpeg-selects-shortest-movie-but-leaves-full-length-audio

Comment: @mayurkukadiya It's working when both files are different. But in my case, Both stream `video` and `audio`  in one file.

Comment: Video is playing at double speed; do you want to cut audio at half-point, or make it double speed as well?

Comment: Video is playing at double speed, I want to cut audio at half-point. But now I got answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565886/how-to-change-video-speed-by-ffmpeg/55566939#55566939
Do you have another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it worked!!!

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS -i INPUT -i INPUT -filter_complex [1:a]apad -shortest -y -preset ultrafast OUTPUT 2>&1
```

Comment: This command is a mess. Options should be placed in proper order: `ffmpeg [input options] -i [output options] output`, use one `-filter_complex` for all filtering, quoting the filtergraph is recommended, and you should generally map the filter outputs: `ffmpeg -i INPUT -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]apad[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest OUTPUT`

Comment: @llogan In my case, video file and audio file are different and then after both merge in one file. But your command is used in only in video file(with sound).

Comment: @PoojaJadav In that case use `ffmpeg -i INPUT0 -i INPUT1 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[1:a]apad[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest OUTPUT`

Comment: You should check above my answer. It's similar to your answer

Comment: This accepted answer is misleading and does not work for most cases -- video file with sound, as explained by OP: _"In my case, video file and audio file are different .... But your command is used in only in video file(with sound)"_ Thus, changing the question to be specifically -- How to change video speed only while adding a same-speed separated audio stream with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 5):

You can use complex filters

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Comment: In your case, setpts=0.5 is fix. But sometimes We don't know about `setpts`. That time What can we set in `atempo`?

Comment: @PoojaJadav, if you want to speed up the video 2 times, it will be `setpts = (1/2)*PTS` and `atempo=2.0` , if you want 3X it will be `setpts = (1/3)*PTS` and `atempo=3.0` better use pointers than fractional number.
on the other hand if you want to slow the video with factor of 3 then it will be `setpts=3*PTS` and `atempo=0.3` .
There are some good examples in [ffmpeg filter documation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)

Comment: Okay, Let me check.